# Prove $\mathbb R^n$ is complete with respect to non-standard norms

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

[Here is a proof (page 6)](https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnlfafolder/lfa03.pdf) for the completeness of $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to the standard Euclidean norm.

I do understand the proof but I want to try to do the proof by myself for the completeness of $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to the following norm:

$||(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots , \lambda_n)||_∞ := \max(|\lambda_1|, |\lambda_2|, ...|\lambda_n|)$

May I please ask someone to briefly tell me how to prove that with respect to this particular norm? (by using the definition of completeness, namely, every Cauchy sequence converges) Thanks so much.

**I do understand that all norms are equivalent But I just want to know how to prove that with respect to this particular norm directly using the method of showing every Cauchy sequence converges.**

Comment: All norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent! Therefore proving completeness for one norm implies it for all other norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I do understand that But I just want to know how to prove that with respect to this particular norm directly using the method of showing every Cauchy sequence converges.

Comment: If you want to prove it explicitly for that norm, you can consider the coordinates of $x_n - x_m$, where $x_n$ is  cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with your infinity norm. The $\max$ means that all the co-ordinates of $x_n$ form a cauchy sequence. Then by completes of $\mathbb{R}$ all of these converge. Put these limits in $\mathbb{R}$ back together and you get a limit for $x_n$.

Comment: It is not enough to show that convergent sequences with respect to the Euclidean norm are convergent with respect to $\|\cdot \|$. You must also show that sequences that are $\|\cdot \|_{\infty}$-convergent are convergent  with respect to the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Could you explain why we need to do all that?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $(x^k)_{k \ge 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|-\|_\infty)$. Then for all $\epsilon >0$ there is some $N$ such that for all $k, l \ge N$, $\|x^k - x^l\|_\infty < \epsilon$. Then by definition of $\|-\|_\infty$, for all coordinates $1 \le i \le n$, $|x^k_i - x^l_i| < \epsilon$ for $k,l \ge N$. It follows that $\{x^k_i\}_{k \ge 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence converges to some $x_i$. It follows easily that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x^k = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_2 = \left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$ satisfies the inequalities

> $$\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_\infty\le \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert_2\le \sqrt{n}\cdot \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert_\infty$$

The first inequality is just replacing the sum with only the one term $\sqrt{x_i^2}$ where $x_i=\displaystyle \max_{1\le j\le n} x_j$, and the second follows from replacing **all** of the summands with the max.

But then if the distance in the normal way goes to $0$, then by the first inequality so too does the "new" norm you have listed, because that distance is **smaller** than the original one. So in fact you can prove that $\Bbb R^n$ is complete in the new norm if and only if it is in the way you are used to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guideline for how to show directly that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete with any given norm:

**Step 1:** Show that if a sequence of vectors $v_k = (v_k^1, \ldots, v_k^n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then the components of these vectors form $n$ Cauchy sequences $(v_k^1), \ldots, (v_k^n)$.

**Step 2:** Use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete to show that these $n$ Cauchy sequences $(v_k^1),\ldots,(v_k^n)$ converge to limits $v^1, \ldots, v^n$.

**Step 3:** Show that the sequence of vectors $(v_k)$ converges to the vector $v := (v^1, \ldots, v^n)$.